# When is Mist 0.7.5 estimated time of arrival?

Tags: mist

When is Mist 0.7.5 estimated time of arrival?

Just that. Please don't say two weeks.

Comment: ETA: Two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to observe how many issues are still open.
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/milestones/0.7.5

Based on this, two weeks maybe in not that incorrect ;-)